# How to embed raw html into page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I am trying to embed raw html code into a webpage using javascript. Please tell me what I am doing wrong

```
<div class="header-note">
    <h4>New version available</h4>
    <p id="version"></p>
</div>


<script>
    const version = document.getElementById("version");
    
    const rawCode = "<h1>Test</h1> <p>Hello World</p>"

    version.innerText = rawCode
</script>
```

I will be rendering rawCode from firebase which I know how to do it's just converting the raw code to read correctly.

currently outputs:

```
<h1>Test</h1> <p>Hello World</p>
```

I need output to be:

```
Test
Hello World
```

Comment: You want `innerHTML` not  `innerText `.... `version.innerHTML = rawCode`

Comment: You should not set `innerHTML` to `<p id="version"></p>` - It will be an invalid HTML (You can't nest `h1` / `p` tags to another `p` tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HERE YOU GO

```js
 const version = document.getElementById("version");
    
    const rawCode = "<h1>Test</h1> <p>Hello World</p>"

    version.innerHTML = rawCode
```

```html
<div class="header-note">
    <h4>New version available</h4>
    <p id="version"></p>
</div>
```